# Math problem for work. # of objects fitting into constrained proportions

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

I have a math problem I need help with for my work, any help would be greatly appreciated! Never mind the specifics, here are the parameters:

10 rows or less
46 colums (or less)
Alternate rows MUST have one less   (e.g. 46, 45, 46, 45…)

All these groups must fit into the 46 by 10 space:

1 group of 15
5 groups of 14
9 groups of 13
8 groups of 12
3 groups of 11
1 group of 10
1 group of 9
1 group of 5
1 group of 4

**Special**
1 group of 23 - OR - split into 1 group of 10 and 1 group of 13
And
1 group of 17 - OR - split into 1 group of 10 and 1 group of 7

Groups cannot spill onto other rows except the 2 special groups

Can this be solved? Or will I need to add more columns? I CANNOT add more rows.
I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I do not understand the formulation of the problem. It sounds like you have to put a bunch of objects into an array in such a way that each object only occupies one cell and such that each group has to be all in the same row (except the last ones)?

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like you should start with a greedy solution and then update. You would start with the 15 in the first row and 2 of the 14s there as well. But that leaves 3 spaces you can't fill, so you put the 15, a 14, a 13, and a 4. Now in the second row, start with 3 14s, get stuck with 3 spaces you can't fill, so you do 1 14, 2 13s, and 1 5. And so forth. It seems like this greedy procedure will converge, especially since you apparently have 61 spaces to burn.

Comment: yes. each group needs to be bunched together and not separated onto other rows. i was able to match up the numbers nicely until row 8 where i ran out of small-numbered groups to fill the blanks. What i need might not be possible without a group or two bleeding onto another row, but i wanted to see if someone else would be able to find a way to do it.

Comment: Suppose you have an odd numbered row with 40, do you then need exactly 39 or at most 39 in the next row?

Comment: um...exactly 39 up until the last 2 rows. the sides have to be more or less straight until the last rows at the top, which can have less objects and kind of...tapper off. but all the other rows have to have the exact same number of objects (alternating with one less)

Comment: Can you more precisely characterize what is wrong with my attempt? In particular, since my last 5 rows are smaller than the first 5, do I need to move some groups from the first 5 to the last 5 to even it out?

Comment: Okay, so that answer could actually work. the entire space ideally should be rectangular in shape and have the last row with a lot fewer objects in it.  but i might be able to use the structure you gave me. maybe i could put it in other terms. so saw each group represents different types of fruit. we have 15 apples, and 13 oranges. i want all the same fruits together, but not to bleed onto other rows so you can see the group as a whole easier. but we also have black cherries and red cherries. they can be split but the cherries need to immediatley follow each other onto the next row

Comment: I see what you mean. I think from here you should try to move groups around such that the rows go 42 41 42 41 42 41 42 41. Then you have 67 more things to place in the last two rows.

Comment: it would be better to have even rows even if that makes them smaller. But the ideal situation might not be feasible with these numbers

Comment: Well, you can get a fair bit closer to even by just moving the elements smaller than 10 from the big rows to the small rows, moving the biggest elements to the least-populated rows.

Comment: By the way, a less brute force heuristic I thought of: if the rows truly alternated, with the big rows having $x$ things, then you would have $10x-5=399$ so $x=40.4$. Thus you might hope to have the 4 longest rows with 41, the 4 shorter rows with 40, which leaves 75 things to go in the lower two rows (which you said can taper off). Maybe you could do that with 38 then 37?

Comment: Or 39 36, or 40 35.

Answer (score 0):

Does this satisfy the problem constraints?

15 14 13 4 (46, done with 15s and 4s)

14 13 13 5 (45, done with 5s)

14 13 10 9 (46, done with 9s)

14 11 10 10 (45, done with 10s)

13 13 13 7 (46, done with 7s)

14 13 13 (40, done with 14s)

13 12 12 (37, done with 13s)

12 12 12 (36)

12 12 11 (35)

12 11 11 (34, done with 12s and 11s)

I basically did this using a mostly-greedy algorithm by hand: try to fill with big groups, then shrink the groups slightly to fill the empty spaces using small groups. This made it feasible to have rather small rows at the end after running out of small groups, since you have a rather large margin of empty spaces (~60) in your overall array. But I do not know if the small rows are acceptable. Nor do I know if the fact that I split the special groups over non-adjacent rows in some cases was acceptable.